Help me solve this Diophantine equation $xy(x^2-y^2)=pq(p^2-q^2)=rs(r^2-s^2)$
I am solving this Diophantine equation
$$xy(x^2-y^2)=pq(p^2-q^2)=rs(r^2-s^2)$$
where $(x^2+y^2)^2+(p^2+q^2)^2=2(r^2+s^2)^2$,
but I am not able to proceed.
I use Euler method $pq(p^2-q^2) = rs(r^2-s^2)$.
If $s = p$, the equation reduces to solving $p^2 = q^2-qr+r^2$, two solutions of which are,
$$\{p,q,r\}=\{u^2+3v^2, u^2+2uv-3v^2,  4uv\}$$
$$\{p,q,r\}=\{u^2+3v^2, u^2-2uv-3v^2,u^2+2uv-3v^2\}.$$
But L.J.Lander gives the solution
$$\{p,q,r,s\} = \{v^5-2v,  v^5+v,  -2v^4+1,  v^4+1\}.$$
But I am to find integer solutions for the above three equivalent rather than two with specific conditions
$$(x^2+y^2)^2+(p^2+q^2)^2=2(r^2+s^2)^2$$ which will help me to know more about arithmetic progression between square. So, please provide solution or guidance to solve this type of diophantine equation or write  a computer program to get integer solutions.

These are areas of right triangles with, for example, legs $2xy$ and $x^2-y^2$ and hypotenuse $x^2+y^2.$ Not sure how that helps, but it would seem important that $(2xy)^2+(x^2-y^2)^2=(x^2+y^2)^2.$

If you can give a link to the L. J. Lander  reference we might be able to help.

FYI This question has been posted today, but I don't know how to get to it. I suspect it was closed/deleted.

@Calvin  I thought it was posted by the same guy, perhaps self deleted.

(https://web.archive.org/web/20130508210157/https://sites.google.com/site/tpiezas/013).    I got l. J landers refrences from here hope it will help to find solution

I posted this question again because previous one is closed

Reposting a closed question is a good way to get into trouble. You are supposed to edit the closed question to bring it up to standard. Anyway, one family of solutions is given by $x=p=r$, $y=q=s$.

The smallest nontrivial solution of the first equations is $(x,y,p,q,r,s)=(7,3,7,5,8,7)$ (but it doesn't satisfy the second equations).

@Gerry Myerson  I tried till 10^7 but not found

Maybe there aren't any.

@Gerry Myerson, if it is true then how to prove

If I knew, I would have posted an answer, wouldn't I?

For reference, the following results are known for the pythagorean triangles with same area.
According to Sequence of Triplets of Primitive Pythagorean Triangles with Same Area(https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Sequence_of_Triplets_of_Primitive_Pythagorean_Triangles_with_Same_Area),
integer solutions of $xy(x^2-y^2)=pq(p^2-q^2)=rs(r^2-s^2)$ are given below. But it doesn't satisfy the second equation.
                (x,y,p,q,r,s,area), area=xy(x^2-y^2)

                (77, 38, 78, 55, 138, 5, 13123110)
                (2035, 266, 3306, 61, 3422, 55, 2203385574390)
                (1610, 869, 2002, 1817, 2622, 143, 2570042985510)
                (2201, 1166, 2438, 2035, 3565, 198, 8943387723270)
                (7238, 2465, 9077, 1122, 10434, 731, 826290896699730)
                (352538, 2999447,1931103, 2398838,3063347, 3215070,9381843970167926138271390)


Addendum
The formulae for triplets of Pythagorean triangles with Same Area are known below.
(Is there a formula for this specific pattern of Pythagorean Triangles sharing an area?)
It seems that the two families of solutions have no integer solution for $(x^2+y^2)^2+(p^2+q^2)^2=2(r^2+s^2)^2$.
$M_1 N_1 (M_1^2-N_1^2)=M_2 N_2 (M_2^2-N_2^2)=M_3 N_3 (M_3^2-N_3^2)$
1st family (Enrique Zeleny). Special case: $M_1+N_1 = M_2+N_2 = M_3-N_3$
$M_1 = r^2 + rs + s^2;\quad N_1 = r^2 - s^2$
$M_2 = r^2 + rs + s^2;\quad  N_2 = 2rs + s^2$
$M_3 = r^2 + 2rs;\quad\quad\;  N_3 = r^2 + rs + s^2$
2nd family (Tito Piezas III). Special case: $M_1+N_1 = M_2+N_2 = M_3-N_3$
$M_1 = (u + v) (2u + 3 v);\quad N_1 = v (u + 3 v)$
$M_2 = (u + 2 v) (u + 3 v);\quad  N_2 = u(u + v)$
$M_3 = (u + 2 v) (2u + 3 v);\quad N_3 = uv$

Does not follow $(x^2+y^2)^2+(p^2+q^2)^2=2(r^2+s^2)^2$

But there's no requirement that the triangles be primitive, so this misses a lot of solutions.

Yes, I'm just giving  the solutions for reference.

The formula for triplets of Pythagorean triangles with same area(https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2448242/is-there-a-formula-for-this-specific-pattern-of-pythagorean-triangles-sharing-an)
